# Getting table name in a trigger in MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers

is it possible to get table name in a MySQL trigger ? i use trigger to log insert actions on some tables in MySQl and i need the name of the table where the trigger is placed at.

Thanx before :)

Comment: Isn't the trigger table specific already, for one to know which table it is?

Comment: Yes. The CREATE TRIGGER statement must include the table it's associated with.  There's no way to assign a trigger to catch arbitrary tables at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you put triggers on all the tables that require logging.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example:

```
@tablename = OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) 
         FROM sys.objects 
         WHERE sys.objects.name = OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)**
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but did you notice that the question was about MySQL? You are giving an answer that is for Microsoft SQL Server.